# SQL Filter for any 24 hour period

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

I have AccounNumber, TransactionID and Date Time. I want to Filter Account Number which has multiple Transactions (more than 2) on a 24-hour period.
For example: If An Account had 2 Transaction in 24th Jan at 11:58 & 11:59 PM and another one in 12:05 Am that should show up as a result. however, if the same account was used to do a single transaction at 10:00Am. The 10:00 Am transaction shouldn't be present.

Note: It's not last 24 hour. Any 24 Hour.

I tried using the lag() and got the Previous DateTime and Calculated the Difference between the CurrentTransaction and Previous Transaction time. It Does filter the right transactions but When I group it using Account Number. Other transactions that were done on that account are also showing up.

Comment: 12:05 a.m. and 10:00 a.m. on what dates?

Comment: How did you use lag function. Can u share query?

Comment: Try using EXISTS with a correlated subquery to find matching records in the previous 25 hours

Comment: Please show some sample data with expected result.

Comment: What would you like to happen if there are several transactions each day for several consecutive days? Should all transactions show up in the results or should they be grouped or filtered in any way?

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @YasinARLI This is how I used. Select AccountNumber,
DateIssued,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumberToken,FilterDate ORDER BY DateIssued) AS Row_Num,
LAG(DateIssued) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumberToken,FilterDate ORDER BY DateIssued) AS Prev_DateTime
FROM ExampleTable

Comment: Please update your question with additional information, don’t add it in comments

Answer (score 0):

Using some dummy data:

```
create table #transactions
(
    AccountNumber int,
    TransactionId int,
    TransactionDateTime datetime
)

insert into #transactions values
(1,1,'2023-09-25 08:00:00'),
(1,2,'2023-09-28 09:30:00'),
(1,3,'2023-09-28 09:45:00'),
(1,4,'2023-09-28 10:00:00'),
(2,1,'2023-09-20 14:30:00'),
(2,2,'2023-09-21 14:45:00'),
(2,3,'2023-09-22 15:30:00'),
(3,1,'2023-09-28 17:00:00'),
(4,1,'2023-09-26 08:00:00'),
(4,2,'2023-09-27 07:59:00'),
(5,1,'2023-09-28 10:15:00')
```

You can use `EXISTS` to check for the presence of another (different) transaction for the same Account within 24 hours:

```
select distinct
    t.AccountNumber
from #transactions t
where exists 
(
    select * 
    from #transactions t24h
    where t.AccountNumber = t24h.AccountNumber
    and abs(datediff(minute,t.TransactionDateTime,t24h.TransactionDateTime)) <= (24 * 60)
    and t.TransactionId <> t24h.TransactionId
)
```

Results:

| AccountNumber |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

If your data is precise to the second, then alter the comparison in the `WHERE` clause to:

```
and abs(datediff(second,t.TransactionDateTime,t24h.TransactionDateTime)) <= (24 * 60 * 60)
```